# how can i pass data from firestore to a function in react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-firebase

Here is the function i want to pass the data to

```
 function db(threads) {
    setThreads(threads);
    if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
  }
```

Here is my query of the data

```
useEffect(() => {
  firestore().collection('User').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    const list = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      const {  id, name  } = doc.data();
      list.push({
        _id: doc.id,
        id,
        name,
        // add this
        latestMessage: {
          text: '',
          userName: '',
          avatar: '',
        },
      });
    });
    db(list); });
}, []);
```

Please help me out, I've been on this for a while.

I use the latest versions of react-native and firebase.

It keeps showing me this error

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating '_useContext7.threads')
```

*But when I logged them to the console, I could see all the data from the database there.*

i just need the threads.id and threads._id

Comment: Are there any empty strings which you are passing to the firebase?

Comment: Harshit Ruwali, nope

Comment: Please follow the [React-Native documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage) on how to fetch data from Firestore.

Comment: That is directly from the invertase.io website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ciao, try to modify your `useEffect` like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
firestore().collection('User').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
const list = [];
querySnapshot.data().forEach(doc => {
  list.push({
    _id: doc.id,
    id: doc.id,
    name: doc.name,
    // add this
    latestMessage: {
      text: '',
      userName: '',
      avatar: '',
    },
  });
});
db(list); });
}, []);
```

Comment: didn't work, I'm trying to create a context using the data gotten from the function